# How can SO validate one accepted answer per question without a parentPostId column in the votes table?

Tags: support

I can't get my head around this, but the votes table in the data dump has no parentPostId column. Only a voteTypeId, a userId, and a postId. Fair enough, but without a parentPostId, how can you validate that a question does not have more than one accepted answer (in other words, a question post does not have more than one vote with a voteTypeId of 1)?

I can't see how you could validate that in the absence of a parentPostId, but I must be missing something!

Comment: Either I'm doing something wrong, or there are such posts: http://odata.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/q/14629/

Comment: @Kobi: I'm pretty sure that this is just a glitch of the datadump or has a very interesting explanation...but it still is very interesting to see.

Comment: @Bobby No, it's not a glitch in the data dump. Check out [this fellow](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/337/timeline), and more egregiously, [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/3880365/timeline). You can compare [this post](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/posts/69513/timeline) to see your standard multi-acceptance behavior.

Comment: @Grace Note: Oh, it's counting the total times of accepting an answer (wait, was that proper English?), I thought something along this lines, but wasn't sure. I'm always amazed on how many data is backing up SE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It goes via the `Posts` table. Just lookup the `ParentId` of the post with ID `PostId` and then check if `AcceptedAnswerId` is set.